# breakable in tcolorbox not breaking

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi} {(\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=2.28cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%       - Fancyhdr -    %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totpages}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    colback      = white,
    tikz         = {opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe     = black,
    title filled = false,
    colbacktitle = white,
}%%
\NewTColorBox[
    ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
    fonttitle                 = \bfseries,
    coltitle                  =  black,
    title                     = #2,
    before lower              = {\textbf{Solution\quad}},
    #1
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%  DOC Begins   %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{question}
% \lipsum[4]
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
\tcblower
\[
    \lambda = 2\times10^5
    \qquad
    l_0 = 2
\]
% \lipsum[4]
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah \lipsum[4-10]
\end{question}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Why does the `breakable` not working in this case?

Comment: it is not enough to load the library, you must also use it. Check the documentation.

Comment: You load `breakable` library but the box (`question`) is not declared to be breakable. You have to include `breakable` in `question` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, you should not just load `breakable`, you must tell the box if it is allowed to be `breakable`.

I commented the `tikz = {opacity=0.1,transparency group}` to make your example visible and I also added the `{Title}` to your `{question}` environment. As you created a `\NewTColorBox` with two arguments, the first optional but the second doesn't seem to be (`{question}{ O{}mo }` and `title = #2,`).

A MWE follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi} {(\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=2.28cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
  colback      = white,
  %tikz         = {opacity=0.1,transparency group},
  colframe     = black,
  title filled = false,
  colbacktitle = white,
  breakable
}
\NewTColorBox[
]{question}{ O{}mo }{
  fonttitle    = \bfseries,
  coltitle     =  black,
  title        = #2,
  before lower = {\textbf{Solution\quad}},
  breakable,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{question}{Title}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \tcblower
  \[
  \lambda = 2\times10^5
  \qquad
  l_0 = 2
  \]
  \lipsum[4-10]
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]